# Integration (Enterprise Server Data -> Salesforce)

Tags: integration, enterprise

Scenario: I have to push about 2000 records (10 Text Fields each) from an Enterprise Server into Force.com every night (a scheduled activity). I am planning the below approach.

Using the Enterprise API, wanted to understand the viability of implementing the above scenario? Can it handle the above volume?
What other approach you suggest?

Comment: you can also consider using scheduled data loader command-line, which can be configured to push data. it uses the soap api behind the scenes. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Comment: This would be my first blush as well.  Command line = easily scheduled.  And since it is the data loader, it won't matter if that number is 100x more in a year.

Comment: Also take a look at the Jitterbit Data Loader. Really easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

That volume can be easily handled by the Salesforce API. I've done integrations that push 100k records + a day. When you get to that level, it is better to use the Bulk API. At your volumes, you would be fine with the Enterprise WSDL.

Answer (score 2):

2000 records update in a context  salesforce easily allows .The limit of apex is 10000 rows .So even apex webservice will work for your data .Enterprise WSDL is also a good choice as far as your data volume is concerned .

One common best practice is always think about " worst case " scenario .If your Worst case maximum load is 2k records enterprise WSDL is good choice .If your data volumes are unpredictable and may exceed 100K go for the Bulk API.

Comment: Thanks, Is 2K records are the maximum an Enterprise WSDL can handle? I guess it is the maximum per call. In case if I have 10K records will I be able to use Enterprise WSDL approach?

Comment: Ya you may be able to use enterprise WSDL for sure .